# Fill a 3d surface with a gradient rather than solid colour

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, fill, tikz-3d, gradient

I wish to plot a 3d surface based on its outline coordinates provided in a file data.txt.
The following code works as expected.

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}    
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[view={0}{160},
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            zlabel={$z$}]
            \addplot3[green, fill] table[x={X}, y={Y} , z={Z}] {data.txt}; 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: Output]

Now I would like to fill with a non-constant color. Specifically, I would like to fill with a gradient where the color is determined by the y value of the data. How can this be achieved?

This is the data.txt file for completeness:

```
X Y Z
1.0 0.23750000000000004 0
0.9500000000000001 0.23756250000000004 0
0.9 0.23850000000000005 0
0.8500000000000001 0.24256250000000004 0
0.8 0.25350000000000006 0
0.75 0.27656250000000004 0
0.7000000000000001 0.3185 0
0.65 0.38756250000000003 0
0.6000000000000001 0.4934999999999998 0
0.55 0.6475624999999999 0
0.5 0.8625 0
0.45 0.6600000000000001 0
0.4 0.5025000000000001 0
0.35000000000000003 0.39000000000000007 0
0.30000000000000004 0.3225 0
0.25 0.3 0
0.2 0.32249999999999995 0
0.15000000000000002 0.38999999999999996 0
0.1 0.5025 0
0.05 0.6600000000000001 0
0.0 0.8625 0
0.05 0.6600000000000001 0.1
0.1 0.5025 0.2
0.15000000000000002 0.38999999999999996 0.30000000000000004
0.2 0.32249999999999995 0.4
0.25 0.3 0.5
0.30000000000000004 0.3225 0.6000000000000001
0.35000000000000003 0.39000000000000007 0.7000000000000001
0.4 0.5025000000000001 0.8
0.45 0.6600000000000001 0.9
0.5 0.8625 1.0
0.55 0.6475624999999999 0.9000000000000001
0.6000000000000001 0.4934999999999998 0.8
0.65 0.38756250000000003 0.7000000000000002
0.7000000000000001 0.3185 0.6000000000000001
0.75 0.27656250000000004 0.5
0.8 0.25350000000000006 0.40000000000000013
0.8500000000000001 0.24256250000000004 0.30000000000000004
0.9 0.23850000000000005 0.20000000000000018
0.9500000000000001 0.23756250000000004 0.10000000000000009
1.0 0.23750000000000004 0.0
```

Comment: Your data only contains the perimeter of the surface, so there is no information on the z-values of internal points. Hence it is impossible to fill it with well-defined colors. Given a complete data set, one can use e.g. `surf,shader=interp` to color the surface with a gradient. You can then adjust the `point meta` key to get precisely the shading you want.

Comment: @Displayname Thanks for the response! I don't entirely follow since I am able to fill with a constant color as I would expect, I would just like the fill color to be non-constant. But if there is a better way of achieving this I would really appreciate if the solution you suggest could be converted into an answer (even if on a smaller sample set of points).

Comment: You fill the perimeter, or more precisely the projection of he perimeter on the screen. If you want to shade the surface one needs the z-values of the points in the interior. If you have a function that parametrizes the surface this would be very easy, otherwise you need to speficy the data in a "matrix" format.

Comment: @Displayname Ah, I think I follow regarding the projection filling. What can I read to understand more about "matrix" format?

Comment: I would really like to make a plot like this based on observed data (of the boundary) without a parameterization where the interpolation is done in the most obvious way.

Comment: For the format, see section 3.5.1 Surface Plot from Data File of the pgfplots manual. How is your "most obvious way" defined?

Comment: @Displayname Thanks, I'll check that out. The shape actually has a 2d curve (in X and Y) at Z=0 (the first 21 coordinates). This shape is then reflected in the Z dimension such that it becomes a triangle at the bottom (along Y=0). All points along Z=0 should interpolate along the vector toward their unique reflection (i.e. the Y should be constant in each interpolation). Does that make sense?

Comment: It might make sense but you may then rewrite your question accordingly. However, I personally do not think that it is very convenient to implement these prescriptions in pgfplots, you may want to manipulate your data with tools which are really made for this. (I am not saying that it cannot be done with pgfplots, it is just not very convenient.)

Comment: @Displayname Thanks for the advice, what tool would you suggest is better? Would love to make life easier for myself!

Comment: Mathematica can interpolate data, find fits etc.

Comment: @Displayname Oh, I thought you meant a different latex package. I would like the plot to be native in latex if possible. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You may just want to do the graphics in a better image program, then take a screenshot of the final result and use `\includegraphics` to put it into your TeX file.